# Applying fills to an Illustrator line drawing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I have a line drawing in Illustrator (I am very new to this so apologies for how dim I seem to be) and I want to colour it in but it seems my lines are individuals (I drew them with the pencil tool and then a circle around them).

How can I make it so that I can fill (and adjust according the colours in each section)?

It is a drawing a bit like a bicycle wheel (but with uneven spokes) where they are more or less radiating from a point to the outer perimeter. I would like to have each "spoke" in a different colour.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot? It would better help us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shape-builder tool will help with this; it's intended for exactly this task.

Select all the lines you've drawn (I threw a few quick lines and curves down for this explanation):

[image]

Then click the Shapebuilder Tool,
which looks like this:

[image]

Then start clicking on your drawing. You will see it figure out which areas can be closed.

[image]

then pick the colour fill you want in each fill area, click in it with the Shapebuilder tool - and there you go.

[image]

Hope that helps.